# Which unification theories would require WEP violation?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, orbital-motion, equivalence-principle, unified-theories

I was just reading [this article](https://www.cnet.com/science/space/remarkable-result-in-physics-history-general-relativity-passes-yet-another-test/) about how the weak equivalence principle was recently confirmed up to one part in $10^{15}$, for two metal alloys orbiting Earth.

Are there theories that expect the WEP to be violated in some regime?  Which ones, how, and why?

Comment: String theory, I think: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9401069